# I have a function in which i and add a class. I want to also change some state but when i do so the class isn't added

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In this function i change state and add a class.

```
const nextQuestion = (e, state) => {
    if (state === true) {
      setScore((currentState) => currentState + 1);
      e.target.classList.add("quiz__question--true");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.add("quiz__question--false");
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      setQuestion((currentQuestion) => currentQuestion + 1);
    }, "300");
  };
```

When i add the setScore state line the class isn't added but when i remove it the class is added.

Why is this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: don't touch DOM in react directly, it is bad practice

Comment: The advice above is good, but separately: Where and how is `nextQuestion` used?  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I have a list of answers to a question and when you click one of the answers i run this function. If the answer you clicked is correct i want to add a class to this answer for the user to see if it was wright or wrong.

quiz-question--false is wrong and quiz-question--true is correct. But i need to add this to the targeted answer. So i don't see any other way then to manipulate the dom